# Unit Test Coverage with react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, testing, i18next, react-i18next

I have a fairly simple React component with Internationalization features implement using i18next. The version of i18next that I'm using is 11.9.0, and the version of react-i18next I'm using is 8.1.0. The component (and specs) looks something like this:

TestComponent.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { I18n } from "react-i18next";

export class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <I18n ns="translations">
        { t => (
          <p>
            {t('test')}
          </p>
        )}
      </I18n>
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

TestComponent.component.spec.js

```
import React from "react";
import { I18n } from "react-i18next";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import TestComponent from './TestComponent.component';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  describe('Snapshot Test', () => {
    it('it matches snapshot', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);
      wrapper.instance().render();
      expect(wrapper.instance()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying to test this component using Jest Snapshots, but when I check the code coverage for this component, it shows that the t function is not being reached by the coverage checker.

I imagine that this can be resolved by mocking I18n in some way, but none of the examples I've found online which do this have resolved my issue.

Can anybody provide some insight into why the coverage checker isn't reaching the t function here? What needs to be done in order to bump up my coverage for a component like this?

Comment: You are doing a shallow render, that means that only that component is been rendered, not it's children, therefore the i18next provider is not worked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if HOC is valid term for component that renders another component through children callback. Let me know if I have to correct wording.

3 different approaches available:

1. using [`dive()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) you are able to drill through HOC still using `shallow()` render.
2. exporting both HOCed and raw version of component - with writting unit tests for raw version.
3. using `mount()` instead of `shallow()` - as for me it's overkill and may lead to unexpected circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I'll run through them tomorrow. Hopefully we won't need the 3rd, as I like to hold off on mount for integration testing.

Just for clarity, how does the HoC tie into my component (which uses the render component rather than the Translate HoC)? Perhaps that's the missing piece of the puzzle here?

Comment: sorry, cannot understand your question. might you rephrase that?

Comment: So my implementation doesn't use an HoC as far as I understand (the HoC being a function wrapper which wraps the component and passes the t function as a prop). It's using an actual component, which passes the t function to its children.

I'm going to do some research on swapping it out with the HoC, but I don't want that to be the solution, because that would be a large refactor at this stage of the project.

Comment: oh, sorry, sure, your code does not have HOC function. I don't know if there is another term for components that use children callback to pass some data into nested components. anyway `.dive()` still allows you to get children rendered.